# data binding to pivotItem using winjs.repeater

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, winjs, dynamic-binding, pivotitem

I tried to bind data into a pivotItem using Winjs.ui.repeater dynamically but the debugger throws an error and show the base.js, can anyone pls help me out.

```
<section class="page-section" aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div>
            <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot">
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header':'AJJ-MAS'}"> 
                    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" data-win-options="{data: AjjMsb.data}">
                        <section>
                            <label data-win-bind="{innerText:trainnumber}"></label>
                            <p data-win-bind="{innerText:starttime}"></p>
                            <p data-win-bind="{innerText:endtime}"></p>
                        </section>
                    </div>        
                </div>                    
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header':'AJJ-MSB'}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Curly brackets are not required for the [data-win-bind property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh440968.aspx). Let me know if that fixes your problem!